# How to feed in images into the model Keras

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a dataset for the self-driving car. My `X` values are the names of the images. Example would be

```
array([['img_2.png'],
       ['img_3.png'],
       ['img_4.png'],
       ...,
       ['img_6405.png'],
       ['img_6406.png'],
       ['img_6407.png']], dtype=object)
```

I found out that model performs good if we have some kind of `batch_generator`. I found that template code.

```
def batch_generator(image_paths, steering_ang, batch_size, istraining):

  while True:
    batch_img = []
    batch_steering = []

    for i in range(batch_size):
      random_index = random.randint(0, len(image_paths) - 1)

      if istraining:
        im = random_augment(image_paths[random_index])
        steering = steering_ang[random_index]
      else:
        im = mpimg.imread(image_paths[random_index])
        steering = steering_ang[random_index]

      im = img_preprocess(im)
      batch_img.append(im)
      batch_steering.append(steering)
    yield (np.asarray(batch_img), np.asarray(batch_steering))
```

I changed this function to for my use but when i apply it.

```
x_train_gen, y_train_gen = next(batch_generator(X_train, y_train, 1, 1))
x_valid_gen, y_valid_gen = next(batch_generator(X_valid, y_valid, 1, 0))
```

I get the following error `TypeError: Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object`. I understand the error, image is not an array but a string. How can i convert string of the image path to the array

Answer (score 1):

It's because at some point you converted `X_train` and `y_train` into numpy arrays instead of image paths.

That's why python is complaining. You were probably doing something else with the code which needed you to convert the entire training dataset, but now you don't need that because you have `imread()` in the `batch_generator` function. I'd go back to earlier in the code and recreate `X_train` and `y_train` as the file paths to the images, and then re-run this portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing in the `img_preprocess()` function but from what I see there are 2 possible problems:

1. You have to append the path to the image to the image name: `path_to_image = path_to_image_dir + '/' + image`
2. You have to actually open the image to get it's array. You can use Pillow or OpenCV:
   `PIL.Image.open(path_to_image)` or `cv2.imread(path_to_image)`